# Banco de dados loca + node.js

Tags: node.js, firebird, microsoft-access, sqlite3, localstorage

Estou trabalhando num projeto usando o node.js.

Preciso usar um banco de dados local, porém eu queria conciliar desempenho com segurança, e caso seja possível, portabilidade também.

Eu só conheço o MS Access (.accdb) e o Sqlite3.

```
[MS ACCESS]

Prós:       Senha
Contras:    Lento, Tem que instalar o Microsoft JET (pois com ODBC é mais lento ainda)
Plataforma: Windows

[SQLITE3]

Prós:       Rápido, Não precisa instalar nada (o node.js suporta por padrão)
Contras:    Não tem como colocar senha
Plataforma: Várias
OBS: Poderia criptografar os dados, mas um SELECT com 5 mil dados demoraria um pouco
     pra descriptografar cada campo dos registros.
```

Alguém conhece algum outro banco de dados local que eu possa usar, e que se possível não precise instalar nada no computador (no máximo um módulo no node.js), e que funcione pelo menos no Windows e Linux?

Vi na internet o Firebird, no benchmark ele mostrava ser muito rápido, mas não entendi se ele é local, pois vi um exemplo que setam o caminho do arquivo, mas também tinha um IP.
Alguém poderia falar mais a respeito?

Obrigado.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Existem muitas opções para sua necessidade.**

Verifique essa biblioteca [TaffyDb](http://www.taffydb.com/),

> uma biblioteca opensouce que traz recursos de banco de dados em seus
>   aplicativos JavaScript.

**Caracteristicas:**

> Tamanho de arquivo pequeno, consultas extremamente rápidas JavaScript
>   poderoso motor de seleção de dados centric Recursos inspirado de banco
>   de dados, tais como contagem, atualização e inserção Apoio cross
>   browser robusta Facilmente estendido com suas próprias funções
>   Compatível com qualquer biblioteca DOM (jQuery, YUI, Dojo, etc)
>   Compatível com o Server Side JS

**Outra Alternativa**

Esses dias descobri um recurso interessante, se chama [DIVSHOT](https://divshot.com/), uma plataforma de hospedagem html5, que foi recem comprada pela google, para integrar com outra tecnologia chamada [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/), feito sob medida para o desempenho e a produtividade do desenvolvedor

Verifique os recursos acima expostos e veja se encaixa na sua necessidade.